# Simultaneous Deployment of Multiple Gadgets?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

Is it possible to use multiple charges of the same gadget at the same time?

For example, can I place two Fuze charges on two different windows, then activate them at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is only one operator who can deploy multiple special gadgets and activate them simultaneously: **The Japanese Offensive Operator Hibana**.

Hibana can fire her X-KAIROS breaching pellets up to three times, when she chooses to detonate them all operational (that haven't been jammed by Mute or destroyed) pellets **will be detonated simultaneously**. This means that you can either open up three separate walls/floors simultaneously, or one large hole, or even only deploy one or two and save the rest to fire and detonate later.

**All other Operators with triggerable deployables can only manually activate them one at a time.**

Answer (score 3):

No you cant do that, with any gadget in Rainbow 6.

Any Attacker Gadget in the current version of R6 can only be deployed 1 at a time.

That goes for breach Charges, operator gadgets etc.

If you could prep 3 cluster charged and let them all go at once, you could instantaneously clear out an entire floor. 
That would be too OP.